# Windows 7 Dell 1545 rotate screen and change wallpaper

Tags: windows-7, resolution, hotkeys, portrait

I recently bought a second monitor and hooked it to my laptop. I like to put the monitor in portrait mode when coding and i can do this with igfx but i was wondering if there was a way to make a keyboard shortcut that will rotate my display 270 degrees and change my wallpaper to one that fits the 1050 X 1680 portrait resolution, and then have a key that rotates back to normal and resets my wallpaper? I have googled to no avail, I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Intel, the default rotation keys are Ctrl-Alt-Up for normal landscape, -Down for upside down, -Left and -Right for portrait.

It's under Options and Support/Hot Keys Manager on the latest version of the Intel Control Panel. I don't remember what it was on the older version, but it was there, too.

That won't change your wallpaper, though, you'd have to set up an event in the Task Scheduler to watch for resolution changes to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) for this. In it you can create your display profiles, save them and assign hotkeys to them.